# VS2010 Publish do not copy additional folder from Content folder

Tags: visual-studio-2010, asp.net-mvc-3, publish

we are developing a web application using MVC3 and VS2010. We have some pdf files under Content\PDFFiles folder. when we publish the website to our server using "File System" publish method, it does not copy the "PDFFiles" folder to the server. however it is copying the other folders (images, themes) from "content" folder. "PDFFiles" folder is additionally added to have pdffiles used by our web application.

anyone know the reason behind it?

Thanks,

Answer (score 17, accepted):

In the Visual Studio Solution Explorer when you right-click on each of the items (files) and select Properties what is the Build Action? Is it Content? If not give that a try.

Answer (score 1):

You can also include an extra folder with all its contents editing the publish profile: http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/deployment/visual-studio-web-deployment/deploying-extra-files